# How to create function in SQL Server for the following scenario

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2012

I need to create a function which returns a string. Input to function is `studentid`:

```
select * 
from StudentReference
where studentid = ?
order by Subid
```

Table format is like this:

```
studentid  subname    subid 
------------------------------
1          math         2
1          sci,xx       3
1          social       1
```

Function input is `studentid`, it should order by `subid` as above and function should return string  `social~math~sci,xx`

Can anybody give an idea ?

```
select 
    T1.studentid,
    stuff((select '~' + T2.subname
           from Studenttable as T2
           where T1.studentid = T2.studentid
           for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') as subname
from 
    Studenttable as T1
group by 
    T1.studentid
```

How to convert above logic as studentid as i/p for table order by subid in function?

Comment: is this homework? show us what you've tried.

Comment: select T1.studentid,
       stuff((select '~'+T2.subname
              from Studenttable as T2
              where T1.studentid = T2.studentid
              for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 1, '') as subname
from Studenttable as T1
group by T1.studentid

Comment: How to make this which takes i/p for one studentid and order by subid